# No module named 'sage.all'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, importerror, sage

Im going to use sage module in my Django web application so in my python virtualenv v3.6 I installed sage using pip. when I run my script to use sage I get the following error:

```
  Exception Value: No module named 'sage.all'
```

I read some posts that sage has its own python. does it mean that I can not use sage in my python virtualenv?

Comment: have you activated virtualenv before running that script ?

Comment: yes, I did :) I even can import sage itself in python console.

Comment: @Nima what operation system did you use?

Comment: @florian.isopp Ubuntu

Comment: look here to install sage in python : https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html

Answer (score 3):

`pip install sage` installs a [version 0.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/sage/) of a package that doesn't have any code inside, just an empty `__init__.py`. It's certainly not that `sage` you want to install. You have to find out which `sage` you really want. Do you mean [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/index.html)?

Comment: Yes I mean SageMath.

Comment: In that case, you definitely can't install it using pip; it's a VERY large and complex thing.  You may wish to look at the [Sage legacy notebook](https://github.com/sagemath/sagenb) for a web app perhaps along the lines of what you are thinking.

Comment: @florian.isopp It's hardly new — I gave a pointer to doc.sagemath.org in my answer more than 2 year ago.

Comment: @phd thats correct, haven't seen the links destination.
Anyhow I m currently in the process of integrating sage into Windows to use it in python scripts. But I am still struggling with that..

Comment: Same here. Still struggling with Windows 10 latest updates and I really don't know why. In specific, I cant get it to be recognized from VS Code no matter what. I will be failing my assignment if I don't have it fixed until the 15th of July unfortunately. Should I try working on Ubuntu via a VM ?

Answer (score 2):

sage or sagemath is not available on PiPy. The packages installed during `pip install sage` and `pip install sagemath` are unrelated to sage and sagemath. You can install sagemath from `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath
```

but it might not work with python environment like you expected.

However, you can install them with `conda-forge`.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install sage
```

Alternatively, you can install sage using `mamba`.

```
conda install mamba
mamba install sage
```

For more information please refer to the GitHub repo of [sage](https://github.com/sagemath/sage). I have added the instructions required for sage installation using PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

SageMath can be installed from several package managers,
including the standard package managers of several
operating systems.

In particular, SageMath is packaged for
Arch Linux, Conda, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo, Nix.

For more details see the
["Distribution" page on the SageMath wiki](https://wiki.sagemath.org/Distribution).

The Sage library currently cannot be pip-installed.
Work on that is tracked at:

- [Sage Trac ticket 21507: Make sagelib a pip-installable Python source package, listed on PyPI](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/21507)