# How can I translate this SageMath code to run in Python?

Tags: python, translate, sage

What do I have to do to make this code run in Python? I got the code from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914288/how-to-find-the-approximate-basic-period-or-gcd-of-a-list-of-numbers). If I run it in a SageMath workbook on [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/), it works with no adjustment needed. When I run it in Python after importing sage and numpy, I get various name and attribute errors.

```
def mean_x(factor, values):
    return sum([cos(2*pi*v/factor) for v in values])/len(values)

def mean_y(factor, values):
    return sum([sin(2*pi*v/factor) for v in values])/len(values)

def calculatePeriodAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = sqrt(mx^2+my^2)
    return appeal

def calculateBestLinear(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values).n()
    my = mean_y(factor, values).n()
    y0 = factor*atan2(my,mx)/(2*pi).n()
    err = 1-sqrt(mx^2+my^2).n()
    return [factor*x + y0, err]

def calculateGCDAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = 1 - sqrt((mx-1)^2+my^2)/2
    return appeal

testSeq = [0,125,211,287,408,520,650,735,816,942,1060] 
gcd = calculateGCDAppeal(x,testSeq)
agcd = find_local_maximum(gcd,2,100)
print(agcd)
plot(gcd,(x,2,100))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error is

```
RuntimeError: Use ** for exponentiation, not '^', which means xor
in Python, and has the wrong precedence.
```

Once that is fixed, there are various missing imports.

Find each of them with Sage's `import_statements` function.

```
sage: import_statements(x)
from sage.calculus.predefined import x

sage: import_statements(sum)
from sage.misc.functional import symbolic_sum

sage: import_statements(cos)
from sage.functions.trig import cos

sage: import_statements(sin)
from sage.functions.trig import sin
```

In the end the code might look like:

```
from sage.calculus.predefined import x
from sage.misc.functional import symbolic_sum as sum
from sage.functions.trig import cos, sin

def mean_x(factor, values):
    return sum(cos(2*pi*v/factor) for v in values) / len(values)

def mean_y(factor, values):
    return sum(sin(2*pi*v/factor) for v in values) / len(values)

def calculatePeriodAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = sqrt(mx**2 + my**2)
    return appeal

def calculateBestLinear(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values).n()
    my = mean_y(factor, values).n()
    y0 = factor*atan2(my, mx)/(2*pi).n()
    err = 1-sqrt(mx**2 + my**2).n()
    return [factor*x + y0, err]

def calculateGCDAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = 1 - sqrt((mx - 1)**2 + my**2)/2
    return appeal

testSeq = [0, 125, 211, 287, 408, 520, 650, 735, 816, 942, 1060]
gcd = calculateGCDAppeal(x, testSeq)
agcd = find_local_maximum(gcd, 2, 100)
print(agcd)
plot(gcd, (x, 2, 100))
```

Search Ask Sage for "import_statements", some answers there
go into more detail on this topic.

- [Search import_statements on Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/page:1/query:import_statements/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to run Sage scripts as Python scripts. Basically, Sage involves a pre-processor that is responsible for all the imports and converts, for example, a floating point value `x` to `RealNumber(x)`, which is a Sage-specific type.
You can find the more detailed answers in the FAQ section in Sage documentation here https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/faq/faq-usage.html#what-exactly-does-sage-do-when-i-type-0-6-2