# Using sage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

I'm confused as to how to use sagemath in python, all I know is you cannot do `pip install sagemath`

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039916/no-module-named-sage-all?r=SearchResults&s=2|57.7562](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039916/no-module-named-sage-all?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C57.7562)

And all I could find were articles saying to use `from sage.all import *`, which produces the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.all'`

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'sage.all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039916/no-module-named-sage-all)

Comment: The post you link to answers your question; what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't understand how to fix said error

Comment: I too tried to install sage  on colab but it shows no module sage.graphs.I need to import DiGraph. I ran `!  pip install sagemath sage-package`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [comments in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039916/no-module-named-sage-all), install sagemath instead with `conda` (not pip) and use the same code:

```
from sage.all import *
```