# How to remove this error in python ? no module sage all

Tags: python, sage

i  installed sagemath .i added this line in my pyhton file .but when i run python myfile.py it takes this error :

```
from sage.all import *


error: no module named sage.all
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039916/no-module-named-sage-all ?

Comment: please provide the code that is throwing this error

Comment: If there is no problem with the method call, is it the same python environment for installing the module and executing the script?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes no it doesnt . i

Comment: @testfile  from sage.all import *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you installed SageMath, it might be
using the system Python or ship its own.

To be able to run

```py
from sage.all import *
```

you need to use Sage's Python.

If `sage` is in your `PATH`, this might be achieved by running

```
$ sage --python myfile.py
```

instead of

```
$ python myfile.py
```